# Symfony FormType getParent vs Inheritance

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

When creating a custom field in Symfony, there is a method we define **getParent**

We define our class by extending from **AbstractType** class, then return a parent type using **getParent** method. instead of extending from parent class.

I want to know the philosophy behind this approach.

Is it possible to define my custom type like:

```
class ImageType extends FileType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image';
    }
}
```

instead of this :

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'file';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image';
    }
}
```

If can, then what is the difference between these two approach?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is old, but if you are interested in the topic, check https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3879. 

The "correct" way to create form inheritance in Symfony2 is the second approach. They've created their custom inheritance system for forms due to some limitations of the Form-Extension system that they had designed. I think they should redesign the extensions system, but that's what we have for the moment.

Comment: * If you don't know the difference between Form-Inheritance System and Form-Extensions System in Symfony2, read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Comment: Don't get confused by Webmozart's description of issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3879 ... in the end the issue was closed without going for the proposed solution. So you *still* need to specify the `getParent()` method.

Answer (score 9):

There are two main differences:

- The first one is about `FormTypeExtension`s. These extensions modify certain form types (e.g: they could change/add some default options, or even add a field).
  Using the first approach (e.g. **Inheritance**), **all** extensions for the `FileType` type will be applied to the `ImageType`, but using the second approach (e.g. **getParent**), they won't, thus you have more control over your structure.
- The second difference is about modifying the behaviour of the parent form inside child form, using `buildForm` and `buildView`.
  Using the first approach (e.g. **Inheritance**), will **override** the base class's methods if you provide them in child, but the second approach (e.g. **getParent**) will **add** the child's logic to that of parent.

Consider the following example:

```
    // FileType
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
    }

    // ImageType
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
    }
```

- #### Inheritance:

  form fields: [**email**]
- #### getParent

  form fields: [**name**] [**email**]

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to extend using AbstractType.  This is used for displaying and building a form and is not a simple entity that you are extending.  The base type, FileType in your case, relates to an file with specific methods and you will be allowed to easily override them but extending through AbstractType and can add new fields.  If you extended FileType, I do not think Symfony2 would load any new functions properly.

I think the first method is more compact and would like to use it, but I think this would cause problems if you are adjusting the buildView or setDefaultOptions, or adding another method that was not part of the base type.